# How to hide element after keyframe animation

Tags: css

I'm trying to hide an element with text after a keyframe animation:

```
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="alignMe">
        <p>Zoom mit</p>
        <p>zwei Fingern</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
@keyframes w100 {
        0% {
            height: 0%;
            opacity: 0;
        }

        25% {
            height: 30vw;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        75% {
            height: 30vw;
            opacity: 1;

        }

        100% {
            height: 0vw;
            opacity: 0.5;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    }
```

Now I got the problem that the text is remaining when animating the height of the parent. I solved it by setting `visibility: hidden;` at the 100% state of the animation. Is there another way of animating this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right - the solution was just to add `overflow: hidden;` to the parent element. Solving all my problems.